# How to handle pop up windows Java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

For example, [TjMaxx](https://tjmaxx.tjx.com/store/index.jsp)

When the user navigates for the first time pop up window shows up, sometimes 2, and it's hard to catch and move on. I tried try catch, but it does not work, because it opens some windows that I cannot see. How to catch all windows and dismiss them all for the guest user?

```
 try {
        WebElement closeWindowPromo = driver.findElement(By.xpath
                ("//div[@class =\"bx-row bx-row-submit bx-row-submit-no  bx-row-2uaILGf bx-element-1360650-2uaILGf\"]//button[@data-click = 'close']"));
        WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By) closeWindowPromo));
        System.out.println("Element is visible");

    } catch (NoSuchElementException n) {

        System.out.println("Element is invisible");
    }
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking on the *close* button try to click on the element with text as ***I don't want free shipping*** inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[class*='bx-row-submit-no'] > button.bx-button[data-click = 'close'][type='reset']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='bx-button' and @data-click = 'close'][@type='reset' and contains(., 'shipping')]"))).click();
  ```